# Incoherent pivot table results using extarnal data connection vs copied table

Tags: pivot-table, powerpivot

I am facing a pivot table issue using external data connection.

I have an excel file that contains information on different lines.

I created external files with various pivot table to organize the data in the source file depending on the needs.

A local pivot table copied in the external file provides 1 answer. The same pivot table based on external data connection provides incoherent information.

same pivot table with different results:

[image: same pivot table with different results]

When double-clicking on the results, the incoherent pivot table extracts information that is not in line with the data actually present in the source data file.

extracted information by clicking on the erroneous pivot table:

[image: extracted information by clicking on the erroneous pivot table]

Sorry, I cannot add the third screen capture (limited rights as a new member)

One side effect :
On the erroneous pivot table, the drag-down list for filtering the "WBS - SO" column is complete with the correct pivot table (contains all the possible values) while in completely incomplete with the erroneous table (contains only numerical values, and I am not sure that it contains all the possible numerical values)

I have searched the Net for Pivot Cache information and tried some of the solutions proposed but none worked.

I have tried classical pivot and power pivot with the same result.

Any idea extremely welcomed since I have been looking for a solution for 2 weeks.

Thank you.

Comment: This does not look to me like a programming question and you will likely more chances to get an answer on another StackExchange site.

Comment: Argh! You are absolutely correct. I posted here because I also use a lot of code around these pivot tables and this code is not reliable since the data it uses is corrupted. Therefore I often rely on Stackoverflow for finding solutions.Thank you for your vigilance.